# SQL: Pull Out Most Recent Added Date From Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, max

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I am currently trying to work on a query to pull back certain records in a query based on an ID's most recent added date.

Here is some sample data I have below. The 3 field names are `ID`, `Description` and `Date`. `ID` comes from the table `Detail`. `Description` and `Date` come from the table `Trend`:

```
ID  Description   Date
57     Used       3/9/13
57      New       1/3/13
58      New       2/4/14
59      New       11/2/16
60      Poor       6/23/15
60      Used       2/4/14
```

From this table above, I want to get the ID information with the most recent date. For example, I should return back the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 5th rows. It should get rid of the 2nd and 6th rows. Basically returning one row for each ID with the most recent date.

This is the code I currently have and I believe I'm close...but not sure where  am going wrong.

```
Code:    

SELECT A.ID, B.Description, CAST(MAX(B.Date) AS DATE)
FROM   Detail A
INNER JOIN Trend B
ON A.TrendID = B.TrendID
GROUP BY A.ID, B.Description
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MAX` window function to get the latest date per id and select only those rows.

```
select ID, Description, Date
from (SELECT A.ID, B.Description, B.Date, MAX(B.Date) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID) as max_date
      FROM   Detail A
      INNER JOIN Trend B ON A.TrendID = B.TrendID
     ) t
where Date=max_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.ID, 
           B.Description, 
           CONVERT(DATE,B.[Date],1) [Date],
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID
                                  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,B.[Date],1) DESC)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```